# Should loaded libraries be left on stack?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

I am preparing my state and loading libraries like so:

```cpp
luaL_requiref(L, "libname", luaopen_libname, 1);
```

After that, when I look at the stack, I can see that every library leaves a value on it (the stack). Should it be like that or should I pop the values?

Comment: Yes, you can pop them if you don't need the values right now.